# How to automate QT desktop application (cross-platform Win + Mac)?

Tags: automation, cross-platform, desktop-application

We have QT based desktop application, please suggest which tool we could select for automate it? Better to have tool with js language. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot of information to go off of but if you're looking for a testing framework to automate a Qt application you could look at Squish for Qt. I've had success using it. I believe it supports writing tests in javascript (personally have only used ruby).

https://www.froglogic.com/squish/editions/qt-gui-test-automation/